# Environment variable with JSON value for Spark (spark.yarn.appMasterEnv)

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm converting an application that was written to run in Spark standalone mode to run on yarn.  In standalone mode, we pass some configuration into the application by setting environment variables in spark-env.sh.

This doesn't work in yarn, instead one sets parameters spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.[ENV_VARIABLE] in either spark-submit or in spark-daemon.conf to get the variable to the driver.  Because of the content of the variables, we want them set in spark-daemon.conf.

I'm able to get values set, but if they're json data, any quotes are stripped out of the value, rendering invalid JSON.  For example:

```
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.MY_JSON_LIST "[{\"myprop\":\"propval\"},{\"myprop\":\"prop2\"}]"                                                                                                    
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.MY_JSON_OBJ "{\"a\":\"b\"}"                                                                                                                                         
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.MY_JSON_LIST2 '[{"myprop":"propval"},{"myprop":"prop2"}]'                                                                                                           
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.MY_JSON_OBJ2 '{"a":"b"}'                                                                                                                                            
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.MY_JSON_LIST3 "[{\\"myprop\\":\\"propval\\"},{\\"myprop\":\\"prop2\\"}]"                                                                                            
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.MY_JSON_OBJ3 "{\\"a\\":\\"b\\"}"
```

Yields the following values when pulled out of the environment in the driver:

```
MY_JSON_LIST: [{myprop:propval},{myprop:prop2}] 
MY_JSON_OBJ: {a:b} 
MY_JSON_LIST2: [{myprop:propval},{myprop:prop2}] 
MY_JSON_OBJ2: {a:b} 
MY_JSON_LIST3: [{myprop:propval},{myprop:prop2}] 
MY_JSON_OBJ3: {a:b}
```

None of these are valid JSON.

So the question is: how can I get arbitrary text (in particular, properly-formed JSON) into the driver via environment variables set on the server?

Comment: A partial answer: no surrounding quotes, and double-escape quotes:  `spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.MY_JSON_OBJ {\\"a\\":\\"b\\"}`.  This doesn't allow for completely arbitrary text - spaces break it.  But it's a limited solution that can work with carefully-formatted json.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to solve this question as stated.  The solution that I ended up using was to base64 encode the json in the config, then un-encode it in the code.  Thus, the configuration was treated as a string and not mangled by YARN on the way in.

Answer (score 0):

This may help as it's worked for me:

```
'{\"foo\":12345,\"bar\":67890}'
```